# Hibernate Mapping maps doesn't work with a intermediate entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hashmap, mapping, many-to-many

I have a Hibernate ORM issue with many-to-many association implemented with a intermediate entity.

My intermediate entity `PurchaseInvoiceShippingDocument` connects multiple `PurchaseInvoices` with multiple `ShippingDocuments`;

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PURCHASE_INVOICE_SHIPPING_DOCUMENT")
public class PurchaseInvoiceShippingDocument
{
    @Embeddable
    public static class Pk implements Serializable
    {
        @Column(name = "PURCHASE_INVOICE_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
        private Long mPurchaseInvoiceId;

        @Column(name = "SHIPPING_DOCUMENT_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
        private Long mShippingDocumentId;

        public Pk()
        {
        }

        public Pk(Long pPurchaseInvoiceId, Long pShippingDocumentId)
        {
            setPurchaseInvoiceId(pPurchaseInvoiceId);
            setShippingDocumentId(pShippingDocumentId);
        }

        public Long getPurchaseInvoiceId()
        {
            return mPurchaseInvoiceId;
        }

        public void setPurchaseInvoiceId(Long pPurchaseInvoiceId)
        {
            mPurchaseInvoiceId = pPurchaseInvoiceId;
        }

        public Long getShippingDocumentId()
        {
            return mShippingDocumentId;
        }

        public void setShippingDocumentId(Long pShippingDocumentId)
        {
            mShippingDocumentId = pShippingDocumentId;
        }
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    private Pk mPk;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, targetEntity = PurchaseInvoice.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PURCHASE_INVOICE_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private PurchaseInvoice mPurchaseInvoice;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, targetEntity = ShippingDocument.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "SHIPPING_DOCUMENT_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private ShippingDocument mShippingDocument;
```

In PurchaseInvoice and ShippingDocument i can access `PurchaseInvoiceShippingDocument`;

```
@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, mappedBy = "mPurchaseInvoice")
private Set<PurchaseInvoiceShippingDocument> mPurchaseInvoiceShippingDocumentSet = new HashSet<>();
```

This works, but when i want to remove a PurchaseInvoiceShippingDocument i have to iterate through `Set<PurchaseInvoiceShippingDocument>` and check each `ShippingDocument` (or `PurchaseInvoice` on the other side).

Therefore i want direct access to ShippingDocument (or PurchaseInvoice on the other side).
I can use a Map mappings for this;

```
@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, mappedBy = "mPurchaseInvoice")
@MapKey(name = "mShippingDocument")
private Map<ShippingDocument, PurchaseInvoiceShippingDocument> mPurchaseInvoiceShippingDocumentMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

This builds, but the Map is always empty (while the database is filling up).
The code checker from IntelliJ produces a warning;

[image]

What is wrong with this code?
Why is mShippingDocument not found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mapping does work! There was a bug in my test case which created a new `PurchaseInvoice` with every test.
And indeed the prior `ShippingDocuments` aren't connected to this new `PurchaseInvoice` (and the map stays empty).

The question remains why IntelliJ produces the warning;

> Cannot resolve attribute 'mShippingDocument'